# MS Outlook Office Add-In migration from Rest API to Graph API: Does Graph work with on-premise Exchange servers?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchange-server, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook Add-in that uses the Outlook Rest API and we're migrating to the Graph API. It does things like downloads attachments, mime-type, and can add attachments, add recipients, and create a draft and send a message on behalf of the user. We support customers that have both Office 365 accounts and on-premise Exchange. Does the Graph API work for on-premise Exchange servers?

Aside, are there known platforms that the Graph API does not work on? I've seen errors with the authentication popups Outlook desktop as well as lack of support for the `OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken()` in Outlook web.
Thank you.

Comment: I assume you are asking if you can call Graph API from add-ins for on-premise Exchange, in particular using OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken? If so, that does not work. This doc discusses getAccessToken: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph

Comment: We are aware that this is an issue important to our developers, and are working on a document to describe the transition process, but do not have a date to share at this time

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Hi, is that document available now?